# How to jump to a div using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: javascript, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts, tampermonkey

On a webpage, I want to create a JS code to jump to specific divisions by pressing keyboard shortcuts. I created a tampermonkey script but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Navigation Hotkeys
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.0
// @description  Navigation hotkeys for 127.0.0.1:5000/*
// @match        http://127.0.0.1:5000/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey) {
            switch (event.code) {
                case 'Numpad1':
                    navigateToElement('series_name');
                    break;
                case 'Numpad5':
                    navigateToElement('sample_data');
                    break;
                case 'Numpad6':
                    navigateToElement('shopping_cart');
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    function navigateToElement(elementId) {
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        if (element) {
            element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
            element.focus();
        }
    }
})();
```